# Team city Oracle error

Tags: c#, oracle, teamcity

I am having trouble with an error regarding Team city and Oracle in the Build Debug and Test step.

The error is as follows,

```
failed
Execute
System.Exception: System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version    8.1.7 or greater.
at System.Data.OracleClient.OCI.DetermineClientVersion()
at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection.OpenOnLocalTransaction(String  userName, String password, String serverName, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean unicode, Boolean omitOracleConnectionName)
at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection..ctor(OracleConnectionString  connectionOptions)
at  System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions  options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.Open()
at ILRetail.eBusiness.Common.Data.DataWrapper.ExecuteReader(String commandText, IDictionary`2 parameters) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\e01a0be7693c6bcf\Dev4.0\Common\src\DataUtility\DataWrapper.cs:line 71
at ILRetail.eBusiness.Common.Data.Database.ExecuteReader(String commandText, IDictionary`2 parameters) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\e01a0be7693c6bcf\Dev4.0\Common\src\DataUtility\Database.cs:line 130
at ILRetail.eBusiness.Common.Data.RepositoryBase.StringQuery(String sql, IDictionary`2 parameters) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\e01a0be7693c6bcf\Dev4.0\Common\src\DataUtility\RepositoryBase.cs:line 105
at ILRetail.eBusiness.Common.DataLayer.DataAccess.Implementation.BankRepository.BankExists(String sortCode) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\e01a0be7693c6bcf\Dev4.0\Common\src\DataLayer\DataAccess\Implementation\BankRepository.cs:line 22
at ILRetail.eBusiness.Common.DataLayer.Tests.BankRepositoryTests.Exists(IPosAdminDatabase db) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\e01a0be7693c6bcf\Dev4.0\Common\test\Common.DataLayer.Tests\BankRepositoryTests.cs:line 17
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
```

Any ideas on why ? Is it just updating Oracle ? Because i'm pretty sure the senior said that Oracle was update? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What version of Oracle client software are you using?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

From error logs:

```
System.Exception: System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version    8.1.7 or greater.
```

Looks like your oracle client needs an update. You need to update your oracle client on the teamcity agent to `8.1.7 or greater.`